# Ajax Files upload progress not working on Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using Ajax for generate the file upload progress bar using following JavaScript code

```
function ulpoad_file(){ 


    var o = $id("progress");

    para = document.createElement("p")
    para.style.height = 2 + 'px'; 
    var progress = o.appendChild(para);
    var file = $id("file").files[0];


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 


    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {      
        var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
        progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";        
        p = 100-pc;
        $id("status").innerHTML = p.toString() + "% Uploaded";
    }, false);


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
        }
    };


    xhr.open("post", "", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    var datas = new FormData();
    datas.append('file', file);


    xhr.send(datas);  

}

function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

This is OK for chrome and several firefox versions.

But "xhr.upload.addEventListener" is not working for Mobile browsers (android browsers in phones and tabs) and Firefox in Linux machines.

Is there any problem with this ?
what is the correct way to use Ajax for progress bar in Mobile browsers also ?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get any resolution for this? It works on Chrome and FF on Android but not on the Android default browser! Seems like the "progress" event is not there in this browser.

Comment: Similar problem here too. Progress event is fired on iOS 7 Safari but not on mobile chrome on iOS. Any news or hints somebody?

Comment: One more here with the same issue, "progress event" is fired on Safari-iPad, but not on Chrome-iPad... I've been searching a solution to this for about 3 hours and nothing.

Comment: Actually at least for Chrome on iOS the progress event doesn't work. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2 and "Known Issues #1"